# Kernel DMA Protection and Device Encryption support is off, even with Intel Virtual Tech enabled. How to enable?

Tags: windows, security, encryption, tpm

## Computer Configuration

[This is the laptop](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/laptops/legion-laptops/legion-laptops-series/legion-y740-(17%E2%80%9D)-gaming-laptop/len101g0012).
Lenovo Legion Y740, Intel core i7 9750H, 17.3" 144Hz GSync, RTX 2080MQ, 16GB RAM, 1TB SSD, Windows 11 Home 21H2 (Build 22000.258)

Intel Virtual Technology: Enabled

Intel Hyper-Threading Technology: Enabled

Secure Boot: Enabled

It does have one Thunderbolt™ 3 USB Type-C port.

It does have TPM 2.0, and the status is "TPM is ready for use".

Windows Security also says "Your device meets the requirements for enhanced hardware security." (that means [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-protection-in-windows-security-afa11526-de57-b1c5-599f-3a4c6a61c5e2#hardwarescore).)

(p.s. - my system had official support for upgrade to Windows 11. It's not "unsupported".)

## Problem

On msinfo32, I see the following -

> Kernel DMA Protection: Off
>
> Device Encryption Support: Reasons for failed automatic device
> encryption: Hardware Security Test Interface failed and device is not
> Modern Standby

## Troubleshoot Done so far

I found [this MS page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/kernel-dma-protection-for-thunderbolt), that says

> If the current state of Kernel DMA Protection is OFF and Hyper-V -
> Virtualization Enabled in Firmware is NO:
>
> - Reboot into BIOS settings
> - Turn on Intel Virtualization Technology.
> - Turn on Intel Virtualization Technology for I/O (VT-d). In Windows 10    version 1803, only Intel VT-d is supported. Other platforms can
>   use    DMA attack mitigations described in BitLocker countermeasures.
> - Reboot system into Windows.

I checked in my BIOS and "Intel Virtualization Technology" is already enabled. I disabled -> rebooted -> enabled -> rebooted; just in case. Still had same situation at the end.

If I plug in any drive to the Thunderbolt 3 port, for example an external usb drive, then a new "Intel(R) USB 3.1 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.10 (Microsoft)" entry pops up in device manager, and that does have "DMA remapping policy" = 00000002. So, looks like it supports DMA remapping.

powercfg /a says my laptop is currently supporting standard standby (S3) only, not modern standby (S0). Found an article that said "set HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\CsEnabled to 0." I did that, but it had no effect.

## Looking for

Any help enabling Kernel DMA Protection and Device Encryption support. Thanks for reading and any possible guidance.

## Screenshots

[MSInfo32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fUoz.jpg)

[Intel Virtual Technology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yiv84.jpg)

[Secure Boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6CNP.jpg)

[Windows Security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5aDh.jpg)

Comment: There is a good chance you simply don't have the required firmware to enable this feature.  I looked at my own system, and while I can't enable Core Isolation, due to drivers that I have installed.  I also had the same status for DMA, but I also have a 9th generation Intel processor, which tells me that might be the reason.